# R programming - Pattern matching (exact word only)

Tags: regex, r, matching

I have just started to learn R programming.

Pls could you provide clarity on below question.

I have a file(XLS) that contains 1 column `(with some keywords, i.e. data, data1, test, test1)`

I have another file (XLS) that contains 2 columns

```
(Column 1 : ID1, ID2, ID3, ID4
Column 2 : data, data_analyst, test, test_analyst)
```

Now, how do i use pattern matching to get the output for all ID's that have a matching pattern and display the pattern name

eg. my output should be as follows :

```
ID1 : pattern matching (data) 
ID2 : pattern not matching 
ID3 : pattern matching (test)
ID4 : pattern not matching
```

Appreciate your response, as i am really confused

Comment: Have you gotten as far as reading the two speadsheets into data frames?

Comment: Welcome to SO. To get the best answers, provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) together with code that you've already tried.

Comment: i tried sapply(XLS$column1, grepl, XLS$column2), but its not giving exact word match. it tries to include data_analyst and test_analyst as well, when i am looking for only data and test

Comment: To use `grepl` here, you need to specify the pattern is preceded and followed by the beginning and end of the line: `grepl("^data$", "data_analyst")` returns `FALSE`, while `grepl("data", "data_analyst")` returns `TRUE`. You can use `paste0` to attach the tokens. Alternately, just use `==`.

Answer (score 0):

First step is to import the XLS files into R. This will import them as data frames, but may not have column names you expect. So you should also set the names to something you recognize.

```
file1 = read.xls("file1", header=TRUE)
file2 = read.xls("file2", header=TRUE)
names(file1) = c("DATA")
names(file2) = c("ID","DATA")
```

You would then do a merge based on DATA.

```
matched = merge(file1, file2, by="DATA")
```

At this point 'matched' includes all the rows that match. So you need to use the match function to find which ones in 'matched' match the ones in 'file1'.

```
a = match(file2$ID,matched$ID)
final = file2
names(final) = c("ID","MATCH")
final[which(is.na(a))],"DATA"] = "pattern does not match"
final[-which(is.na(a))],"DATA"] = "pattern matches"
```

Comment: > file1 = read.csv("1_Data analysis_SITcases.csv", header=TRUE)
> file2 = read.csv("Business_Elements.csv", header=TRUE)
> names(file1) = c("ElementName")
> names(file2) = c("TS_TEST_ID","TS_USER_01")
Error in names(file2) = c("TS_TEST_ID", "TS_USER_01") : 
  'names' attribute [2] must be the same length as the vector [1]
>

Comment: That's a CSV file, not an XLS or XLSX file. Save the Excel file as one of those formats and then try it out.

Comment: Could you advise me , on how to get only matching word..
e.g. output to be data and not data_analyst

var1<-sapply( a$a2 ,grepl, b$a2)

a = (data, data_analyst)

b = 
id1, data
id2,test
when i run sapply with grepl , it gives me output of both data and data_analyst as well

Comment: Hold on, I'm confused on what you're saying. Are you saying you just want a vector of the datapoints that matched? So from your example, you would get a vector c("data","test")?

Comment: dont worry, i think i narrowed it down now. 
pls could you help me on the last line .now output shows as below : 
ID1 "2"                                       
ID2 "1"                                       
ID3 "This is not a  Use case"
ID4 "This is not a  Use case"
i tried your last suggestion [-which(is.na) , it seems not working for above output. it still shows as 2 and 1 instead of "This is a Use case"

Comment: Could you post your code? My suggest to use [-which(is.na)] is only relevant to my own code as a whole. If you don't use the previous lines of code then I have no idea how to help you.